# Changing an existing of MapBox polygon's color

Tags: polygon

I'm attempting to use the following code to change the color of a polygon on my MapBox map, after it's already been added to the map.

```
parishPolygon990 = L.polygon([ vertices ], { color: "#0000FF" }).addTo(map);

console.log(parishPolygon990); // returns #0000FF
console.log(parishPolygon990.options['color']); // returns #0000FF
parishPolygon990.options.color = '#d31603';
console.log(parishPolygon990); // returns #d31603
console.log(parishPolygon990.options['color']); // returns #d31603
```

You can see that the color value for the polygon updates, but the polygon on the map does not change color.

How can programmatically change the color of the polygon on the map after it's been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `setStyle` method of `L.Path` which `L.Polygon` is extended from:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([[45,45],[-45,45],[-45,-45],[45,-45]]).addTo(map);

polygon.setStyle({'color': 'yellow'});
```

Working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vL0rAoKQGhV8zri8mDz7?p=preview

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-setstyle

If you would really want to do it by changing the options object, you'll need to call the `_updateStyle` method of `L.Path` afterwards:

```
polygon.options.color = 'yellow';
polygon._updateStyle();
```

But as the `_` suggests it's an internal method of `L.Path` and is not part of the API so you should avoid using it because it can change in future versions of Leaflet. Just thought i should mention it.

Comment: No thanks, always welcome, i've added the internal method that's called when setting the style, also works, but shouldn't be used